# How TutuApp is being distributed publicly without Apple's app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, apple-developer

TutuApp for iOS is being distributed to public without the App Store.

I know that Ad Hoc is one way to distribute apps but it is limited to 100 devices.

I know that Enterprise in-house is another way but intended for internal to companys. (Apple can revoke the certificate and the App cannot be installed)

So what is the way used by TutuApp. Is it legal?

How Xcode made the `ipa` file without Apple Developer account?

Comment: Probably a tool to [resign the ipa](https://github.com/xndrs/XReSign)? You basically answer all your question, not sure what you wanna ask

Comment: They are probably abusing an enterprise certificate. Once Apple shuts down one cert they will switch to another, their clients would need to keep reinstalling apps each time they need to be re-signed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using [**`Apple Developer Enterprise Program`**](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/), to distribute Apps without uploading to iTunes store, the program uses to create proprietary apps designed for and distributed exclusively to internal organization’s only.

There is instruction to install & trust enterprise developer certificate when you install the app.

[image]

After installing the app, you can check the profile in device

Settings -> General -> Profiles & Device Management -> Enterprise App

[image]

Comment: I would not go as far as trusting a development certificate from a random developer and installing an app that has not been verified by Apple. Not that I trust Apple too much, it is just that this developer probably has good reasons to avoid the verification process.

Comment: Apple not allow its enterprise program to be used like this, TutuApp violates the intended use of enterprise certificates and it won't be surprising if we see their developer account terminated shortly.